# Meter bar not updating

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <style>
        h1 {
            color: white;
        }
        body {
            background-color:  black;
        }
        .scroller {
            background: linear-gradient(#94ff98, green);
        }
    </style>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1 align="center">Fetching data...</h1>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <meter id="prog" value="0" max="100"  style="width: 100%"></meter>
            <script>
                setInterval(
                function () {
                    var prog = document.getElementById("prog");
                    var i = 0;
                    i = i + 1;
                    prog.setAttribute("value", i)
                },
                10
                );
    </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Yes, I know the meter element isn't for progress bars, but im just using it merely for aesthetics and it isn't doing anything at all, really.
So why is it not updating, setinterval only runs once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable declaration of `i` should be moved outside of the `setInterval` callback. The variable `i` is reinitialize to zero for each interval.

Also, it's better to clear the interval after `i` has reached 100.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/5qx46Lt8/1/)

```js
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var prog = document.getElementById("prog");

  i = i + 1;
  prog.value = i;
  console.log(i);
  if (i >= 100) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 10);
```

```css
h1 {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
.scroller {
  background: linear-gradient(#94ff98, green);
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Fetching data...</h1>

<br>
<br>
<meter id="prog" value="10" max="100" style="width: 100%"></meter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code It will help you

```
<script>
        var i = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            var prog = document.getElementById("prog");

            i = i + 1;
            prog.value = i;
            console.log(i);
            if (i >= 100) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 35);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is saying: every 10 milliseconds,

1. access the DOM,
2. 1 declare a variable, assign it's value to 0,
3. add 1 to i (0 + 1 = 1)
4. then set the value of your DOM element to i (e.g 1)

The problem is that your code keeps creating a new locally scoped variable i and setting it to zero each time that function is called.

You need to move i outside the scope of your anonymous function.